# Serialization of an object

Tags: c#

I am Serialing an object using

```
         GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
           {
               info.AddValue("string1",subobject1);
               info.AddValue("string2",subobject2);
           }
```

what will be stored in stream? do the strings also store?
How will be the exact storage format in Stream??

Comment: The exact storage format is a proprietary implementation detail that you shouldn't need to know precisely because it isn't guaranteed. If you need a known format, then use a different serializer. `BinaryFormatter` makes no promises here.

Answer (score 1):

The subobject1 and subobject2 values will be stored.  Yes, the string are also stored, needed to be able to match the name passed to GetValue() during deserialization.

Comment: You cannot get that, the binary serialization format is not documented and subject to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the strings are stored as the keys by which to look up the data during the subsequent deserialization. They would be used in a special constructor of the class being deserialized, something like this:

```
public YourClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)    
{
    //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties        
    this.String1 = (String)info.GetValue("string1", typeof(string));
    this.String2 = (String)info.GetValue("string2", typeof(string));
}
```

Comment: How will be tha exact format that the serialized object stored in stream?

Comment: As Mark and Hans remarks, that is not documented. I guess you could inspect the content of the stream and try to analyze it, but don't think it would be a good idea. Why do you need the exact format?